# Am I suppose to do any statistical test on results?

Tags: statistics, ab-test, hypothesis-testing, experiments, statistical-significance

I am doing an email campaign. Before sending emails to users I divided my user base into treatment and control groups (50-50). Divided the groups in such a way that no difference in user behaviour. I sent email only to treatment group .

I have some other metrics to measure for success of campaign apart from CTR, Open rate. I have the results of those for both groups. Lets say I have 10% rate for treatment and 4.5% rate for control group.

My question here is am I suppose to conduct any Statistical significance tests on results of treatment and control groups? or can I say directly that treatment is doing better than control because 10% > 4.5%?

Note : It is not any assignment kind of project. I am doing a sample recommendation project.

Comment: please "clarify have the results of those for both groups" and what do you want to say - "sample recommendation"